# UITextView .isEmpty not working on keyboard send Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Have a **UITextView** that is submitting character input through the **"Send"** Button on the keyboard. I have tried all of these below, yet it **still** makes it through with no characters.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn  range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (text == "\n") {

        if(textView.text != "" || !textView.text.isEmpty){

          print("still printing")
         //**I dont want it to make it here but it does with no characters in textView after clicking send on keyBoard
        //It still makes it here when send button is pressed and textView is null.
            return false
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

**I have tried these and more...**

```
if(textView.text != "" || !textView.text.isEmpty || textView.text == nil)


if textView!.text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
    [...]
}

if (self.textView.text.characters.count > 0) { }
```

1.) **if (text == "\n")**           means "Send" button has been pressed

2.) **if(textView.text != "")**    checking if textView is null

The textView is null but still makes it through the if statements I have tried above.

Comment: Maybe check it when the button is pressed?

Comment: text == "\n" is when the button is pressed

Comment: could be throwing it off for some reason but i dont know i tried checking for != "\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the new text length you need to use the range and text parameter values as the following:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn  range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let insertedText = text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    if insertedText.count == 1 {
        textView.text = insertedText
    }

    return false
}
```

> **Details:** The shouldChangeTextIn is triggered before the text change on the
>   UITextView. That makes sense because the
>   decision for applying the change is taken in this function `shouldChangeTextIn`?.

Comment: so how do I use the newLength message.text.character.count > newLength?

Comment: your not accounting for "\n" or return true

Comment: I edit it. we are taking \n in consideration by trimming whitespacesAndNewlines

Comment: we don't need to return true. because we are editing the text ourself. textView.text = insertedText

Comment: the functionality works. But when characters are entered it performs "\n" action rather then making it in

Comment: try it your self with a text view. and the return button

Comment: I did try it. it works fine and when I click the return button nothing happen. isn't that what you want?

Comment: I don't know why you are using textview anyway. you should be using textfield.